# Hiberante InValidMappingException - Error performing export : Could not parse mapping document

Tags: hibernate, ant, maven-plugin, hibernate-mapping, java-11

I am attempting to compile the Maven Project(hibernate) with Openjdk11 getting the below exception during the ant job execution but it was successfully compiled with JDK8.

```
    Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document: /Users/rkkp/projb/src/main/java/com/prok/rpt/dao/DateComponents.hbm.xml(FILE)
    at org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.InputStreamXmlSource.doBind(InputStreamXmlSource.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.FileXmlSource.doBind(FileXmlSource.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.FileXmlSource.doBind(FileXmlSource.java:32)
    at org.hibernate.boot.spi.XmlMappingBinderAccess.bind(XmlMappingBinderAccess.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.addFile(MetadataSources.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.addFile(MetadataSources.java:325)
    at com.gvp.antplugin.RSSchemaExportTask.doExecution(RSSchemaExportTask.java:190)
    at com.gvp.antplugin.RSSchemaExportTask.execute(RSSchemaExportTask.java:161)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to build hbm.xml JAXBContext
    at org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.MappingBinder.hbmJaxbContext(MappingBinder.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.MappingBinder.doBind(MappingBinder.java:53)
    at org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.AbstractBinder.doBind(AbstractBinder.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.AbstractBinder.bind(AbstractBinder.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.InputStreamXmlSource.doBind(InputStreamXmlSource.java:43)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:278)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:421)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:721)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:662)
    at org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.MappingBinder.hbmJaxbContext(MappingBinder.java:73)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
    at javax.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil.nullSafeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:122)
    at javax.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil.safeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:155)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:276)
    ... 54 more
```

pom file build tag code

```
 <build>    
    <plugins>           
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
          <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <echo>******** Run schemaExportTask ********</echo>
                            <echo>${project.basedir}</echo>
                            <echo>${project.parent.version}</echo>
                            <echo>${project.parent.directory}</echo>
                            <echo>${TEST_DBTYPE}</echo>
                          <taskdef name="schemaexport" classname="org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExportTask" classpathref="maven.dependency.classpath" />                       
                            <schemaexport properties="${basedir}/src/main/resources/sql/mssql_hibernate.properties" 
                                quiet="false" text="true" create="true" delimiter=";&#10;GO" 
                                output="${project.build.directory}/mssql-schema-std.sql">
                                <fileset id="standardMappings" dir="${basedir}/src/main/java">
                                    <include name="**/dao/DateComponents.hbm.xml"/>
                                </fileset>
                            </schemaexport>
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                    <version>5.1.16.Final</version>
                </dependency
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ant-nodeps</artifactId>
                    <version>1.8.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

HBM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.prok.rpt.DateComponents">
        <id name="startOfDay" column="start_of_day" type="long"/>
        <property name="startOfWeek" column="start_of_week" type="long" index="sow_idx" not-null="true"/>
        <property name="startOfMonth" column="start_of_month" type="long" index="sof_idx" not-null="true"/>
        <property name="year" column="year_col" type="short" index="year_idx" not-null="true"/>
        <property name="month" column="month_col" type="short" index="month_idx" not-null="true"/>
        <property name="weekOfYear" column="week_of_year" type="short" index="woy_idx" not-null="true"/>
        <property name="dayOfYear" column="day_of_year" type="short" index="doy_idx" not-null="true"/>
        <property name="dayOfWeek" column="day_of_week" type="short" index="dow_idx" not-null="true"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

It's a legacy project with an XML-based Hibernate implementation, so there are no issues with the code as it is currently successful with JDK 8. I would like to know if there have been any changes with OpenJDK 11 regarding XML mapping in Ant plugin file mapping.